# how to override a javascript closure function call

Tags: javascript, closures, overriding

I have the following scenario

```
var bar = (function () {

  function foo() {
    console.log("Hello World");
  }

  function bar() {
    foo();
  }

  return bar;
} ());
// override foo before the call
bar();
```

Since foo is being called from the bar function which is returned from inside the a closure, it can be considered that foo is acting like a private property.

I want to know if it is possible to override the `foo` function before the `bar` is called? How many ways can it be achieved?

Here is something that is tried but I was unable to achieve the result.

```
var bar = (function () {

  function foo() {
    console.log("Hello World");
  }

  function bar() {
    foo();
  }

  return bar;
} ());

var _bar = (function () {
  function foo() {
    console.log("Hey there");
  }
  return bar;
} ());

_bar();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to know If it is possible to override the foo function before the  bar is called? How many ways can it be achived?

No, not and keep/reuse the current functionality of `bar`. You could completely replace `bar`, but that's not particularly useful.

`foo` is **entirely private** to the context in which it was created. `bar` has access to it, but nothing else does (well, okay, `foo` has access to *itself*). There's no way to reach into the execution context `bar` closes over and change its `foo` binding unless something explicitly enables that, which nothing in your example does.